# Check if function is being called as goroutine or not

Tags: go, goroutine

Is there any way to find out if a running function was called as goroutine or not?

I've read 'go tour' and I am interested in building a websocket server with golang, so I found this tutorial https://tutorialedge.net/golang/go-websocket-tutorial/

Now I'm wondering if wsEndpoint function from the tutorial is invoked as goroutine (e.g. go wsEndpoint(...)) or not.

I've tried to read http package documentation, but did not get clear picture, just a guess that the handler will be called with go routine. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, HTTP handlers are called in their own goroutine. Note that *every* functions runs in a goroutine, even main. Whether one function runs in a different goroutine from another function cannot generally be determined. Some hacks exist, but they rely on implementation details of the runtime and are therefore not portable or subject to the compatibility guarantees.

Comment: Let's say I need to access some external data from my function for modification, but I don't know whether the function was called in another go routine or not. Then how do I determine if I need to use mutex to serialize access to the data?

Comment: Whether you need synchronization or not is not a runtime decision. It's made when writing the code and when writing the code you already know.

Comment: That's the problem, I think I don't know because I don't know how my functions are going to be called from other packages...

Comment: That's your decision to make; you can either solve a problem yourself or let the user deal with it. Just document if your function is safe for concurrent use. You should have some kind of intuition whether that's a common case or not.

Comment: No, I'm afraid it's other way around: I'm using some package which will call my function, but whether it will call my function via go or not it is not described in that package. So what shall I do? Probably read source codes of that package or find another one with better docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every function is called from a goroutine, even the `main()` function (which is called the `main` goroutine).

And goroutines in Go have no identity. It does not matter which goroutine calls a function.

To answer your "original" question:

> Is there any way to find out if a running function was called as goroutine or not?

If we define this as the function being called with the `go` statement or without that, then the answer is yes: we can check that.

But before we do: I would not use this information for anything. Don't write code that depends on this, nor on which goroutine calls a function. If you need to access a resource concurrently from multiple goroutines, just use proper synchronization.

Basically we can check the call stack: the list of functions that call each other. If the function is at the top of that list, then it was called using `go` (check note at the end of the answer). If there are other functions before that in the call stack, then it was called without `go`, from another function (that places before in the call stack).

We may use [`runtime.Callers()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Callers) to get the calling goroutine's stack. This is how we can check if there are other functions calling "us":

```
func f(name string) {
    count := runtime.Callers(3, make([]uintptr, 1))
    if count == 0 {
        fmt.Printf("%q is launched as new\n", name)
    }
}
```

Testing it:

```
func main() {
    f("normal")
    go f("with-go")

    func() { f("from-anon") }()
    func() { go f("from-anon-with-go") }()

    f2("from-f2")
    go f2("with-go-from-f2")

    f3("from-f3")
    go f3("with-go-from-f3")

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}

func f2(name string) { f(name) }
func f3(name string) { go f(name) }
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/72AIbDXvQM2)):

```
"with-go" is launched as new
"from-anon-with-go" is launched as new
"from-f3" is launched as new
"with-go-from-f3" is launched as new
```

<sup>Note: basically there is a `runtime.goexit()` function on "top" of all call stacks, this is the top-most function running on a goroutine and is the "exit" point for all goroutines. This is why we skip 3 frames from the stack (0. is `runtime.Callers()` itself, 1. is the `f()` function, and the last one to skip is `runtime.goexit()`). You can check the full call stacks with function and file names+line numbers in this [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LDMtj2ZVljl). This doesn't change the viability of this solution, it's just that we have to skip 3 frames instead of 2 to tell if `f()` was called from another function or with the `go` statement.</sup>

Comment: If I'm providing my own function which accesses shared data to another function from some package (for example http package), shall I use mutex to synchronize access to the data? Always?

Comment: @Sergey Yes, HTTP handlers are called from their own goroutines, so if they access data outside of the handler function (that includes write), synchronization is required. For details see [Process Management for the Go Webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529511/process-management-for-the-go-webserver/37531953#37531953)

Comment: Ok, maybe HTTP handlers is not a good example anymore. What if you started using some new package and you don't know the internals of the package, what will you do then? Implement serialized access in your function or look at the sources of the new package to understand what happens there?

Comment: @Sergey Look at its documentation. If it documents that it's safe for concurrent use, then that's good. If not, don't make that assumption.