# Is it possible to augment fmt.print with default indentation level?

Tags: go, gofmt

I am messing around creating modules and interlinking them.

When testing out behaviours I am calling packages that call other packages.

Is there an easy way to modify behaviour of fmt package with indentation level of future calls.
So that parent can sets indentation level +1 before calling child package.

This way when each function prints out output I can easily see cascading dependencies in the stdout:

```
inside main
calling package X
____entering package X
____calling package Y
________package Y hello world
____leaving package X
back in main.
exiting
```

Comment: That is not part of the functionality of the `fmt` package.

Comment: "Is it possible to augment..." No. Go doesn't let you augment things. The best you can do is wrap things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package does not support this out of the box.

However, you can access the call depth with the help of [`runtime.Callers()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Callers), which means you don't even have to maintain the indentation "level" manually.

#### "Proof of concept"

Accessing the call depth is like this (which returns `0` for `main()`, `1` for a function called from `main()` etc.):

```
func callDepth() int {
    pc := make([]uintptr, 100)
    return runtime.Callers(6, pc)
}
```

And using it, an auto-indenter printing function:

```
var tabs = strings.Repeat("\t", 100)

func Println(args ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Print(tabs[:callDepth()])
    fmt.Println(args...)

}
```

Let's see it in action:

```
func main() {
    Println("In main()")
    f1()
    Println("In main() again")
}

func f1() {
    Println("In f1()")
    f2()
    Println("In f1() again")
}

func f2() {
    Println("In f2()")
}
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5E_tTHSmTJ4)):

```
In main()
    In f1()
        In f2()
    In f1() again
In main() again
```

#### Notes

I called the above solution "proof of concept" because it's not a solution handling all cases. You have to decide how you want to handle when new goroutines are launched. When new goroutines are launched, they are not called from `main()`, so the skip frames passed to `runtime.Callers()` should be 1-less (`runtime.Callers(5, pc)` instead of `runtime.Callers(6, pc)`). For how to detect this, see [Check if function is being called as goroutine or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56702183/check-if-function-is-being-called-as-goroutine-or-not/56702614#56702614).

Answer (score 1):

Write a little wrapper around the fmt functions you want to behave like this so they take an extra parameter of indent level

```
package main

import "fmt"

// Println  replacement
func Println(level int, args ...interface{}) {
    for i := level; i > 0; i-- {
        fmt.Print("__")
    }
    fmt.Println(args...)
}

func main() {
    Println(0, "here")
    Println(1, "there")
    Println(2, "everywhere")
    Println(2, "Yes, everywhere")
}
```